# Read online xml file and parse it

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, youtube, sax

I am trying to get comments on youtube videos and parse them using sax. The following is a code that just prints comments given the url. I want to change it to something that takes a url as input from the user and prints the comments. The XML is ONLINE and not saved on local disk, nor do I want to use pre-saved files.

```
public class ReadXMLFile {
    public static void main(String argv[]) {
        try {
            SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
            SAXParser saxParser = factory.newSAXParser();
            DefaultHandler handler = new DefaultHandler() {
                boolean content=false;
                int i=0;
                public void startElement(String uri, String localName,String qName, 
                    Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
                    if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("Content")) {
                        content = true;
                        i+=1;
                    }    
                }
                public void endElement(String uri, String localName,
                    String qName) throws SAXException { 

                }
                public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length) throws SAXException {
                    if (content) {
                        System.out.println("Comment " + i +": "+ new String(ch, start, length));
                        content = false;
                    }
                }
            };
            saxParser.parse("D:\\comment.xml", handler);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you take out all the extraneous newlines in your code and fix the indentation, it'll be much easier for everyone to read and understand what you actually want.

Answer (score 0):

With this you can get the content of a webpage as inputStream:

```
String urlStr = "http://www.stackoverflow.com";
URL url = new URL(urlStr);
URLConnection conn = url.openConnection ();
conn.getInputStream()
```